# Prove that the space is totally-disconnected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Given.**

$$D \text{ - some dense set in ℝ} $$
$$P(D) - \text{power set over D} $$
$$T_{d_E} - \text{canonical topology on ℝ} $$
$$T_D = T_{d_E}\cup P(D) $$
$$T - \text{ topology generated from the subbasis } T_D$$
$$\underline X = (ℝ, T) $$

**Prove.**

$\underline X$ is totally-disconnected.

---

**Attempt.**

If $A \subseteq R, \ card(A) > 1$ and $A$ is **open**, then it contains some $d \in D$ by the definition of density.

Since $\underline X$ is a $T_1$ space, then $\{d\}$ is closed but it's also open in $A$ due to the way $T_D$ is defined. So $\{d\} \neq A$ is "clopen" set in $A$ and hence $A$ is disconnected.

Same goes by the above logic for the case if $A$ is not open but is a neighbourhood containing an open set.

If the above is right then one can handle the cases: $[ a, b], $[a, b), $(a, b]$ and $(a,b)$.

But how can one show that e.g. non-interval set is disconnected: $B = (a,b)\cup(c,d)$?

If the topology defined on $\underline X$ were $T(\le)$ Topology, then one could argue that since $B$ is not an interval then it can't be connected. But $T_D$ is not an order topology, so how can I prove that $B$ type sets are disconnected too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_D$ is not a topology but it is a subbase for a topology, which is probably what's meant here. Taking $D= \Bbb P$ gives us the [Michael line](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/), and this question is meant to generalise this situation, I suppose.

To see that $\underline{X}$ is totally disconnected, take a subspace $A$ having $2$ or more points. If $d \in D \cap A \neq \emptyset$ then $\{d\}$ is a clopen subset of $A$, so $A$ is not connected. Otherwise $A$ has empty interior in the Euclidean topology and $A \subseteq \Bbb R\setminus D$. In the usual topology any $A$ that has empty interior and has two or more points is disconnected (as it's not an interval of any type) and so the same holds for $A$ (which has the Euclidean topology, been disjoint from $D$). QED

Comment: You are right about the problem definition. $T_D$ is only a subbasis. I will correct my mistake now. Can you clarify the last statement? It's just the resulting topology $T$ of $\underline X$, which will be $T = \text{generate_topology_from}(T_D)$ is bigger than $T_{d_E}$ and as such can have some additional disjunctive open sets that can be used to construct some subset of $R$. How do you exclude that possibility?

Comment: @СССР Well, the basic sets are $O$, $O \cap D$ and $\{d\}$, $d \in D$, where $O$ is Euclidean open (it's easy to check they must be open and they form a base). So if $A$ is disjoint from $D$ they basic subspace sets can only be $O \cap A$, so just as it has in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @СССР We even can use $O, O \in \mathcal{T}_{\text{eucl}}$, $\{d\}, d \in D$ as a base, of course. More economical.

Comment: I guess I just didn't see a simple fact that since $A$ is discontinuous in $T_{d_E}$ then there are open sets $A_1$ and $A_2$  in $T_{d_E}$ that can be used to show that fact. Same sets can be reused in case of $T = \text{gen_topology}(T_{D})$ because this $T$ will also contain $A_1$ and $A_2$ (due to $T_{d_E} \subset T_D$).

Comment: @СССР That alone is not enough, we do use $A \cap D= \emptyset$ too. In general a larger topology can have fewer disconnected subsets.

Comment: Do you have an example of that? I thought that if $T_1 \subset T_2$. Then any disconnected set in $ \underline X_{T_1}$ will also be disconnected in $ \underline X_{T_2}$.

Comment: @СССР Yes, that's true indeed.